# libcurl authentication on iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, libcurl

Is there any way i can use libcurl library in Iphone to authenticate?

Comment: What do you really want to do? Foundation provides NSURLConnection and friends which should cover vast majority of libcurl's functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Although libcurl isn't provided by the OS, you can build your own static library (details here: http://www.creativealgorithms.com/blog/content/building-libcurl-ios-42).  Basic authentication is handled automatically.  All you need to do is add the username:password to the URL like so:

`http://username:password@www.hostname.com/index.html`

Just don't forget to percent-escape any reserved characters in the username or password.